# Angular - Pending function until calling deferred.resolve

Tags: angularjs, service

I made service that might take more than a minute and return some data.
Here some part of service code.

```
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    //check data is in cache
    //if not, some process (take some time)
    deferred.resolve( data);
   });
return deferred.promise;
```

and tried to use this service on two js file in a row. This is part of js code that call service.

```
myService.get().then( function( data) { //works });
```

This is how it is supposed to work.

> load A.js -> service load -> get data (take some time) -> save data in
>   cache -> process A.js -> load B.js -> service load -> get data from
>   cache -> process B.js

BUT since A.js and B.js file load at almost same time, this is how currently work.

> load A.js -> service load -> get data (take some time) -> meanwhile load B.js -> service load -> **get data (take some time) duplicate loading data** -> ...

How should I pending either A.js or B.js service if one of them already works on with service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently came across the same problem as well. Here is what I did to solve it.

The idea is creating a flag to identify if a http request is still in progress, and use $timeout to retry until the previous request has been resolved. Before doing retry, a defer object will be returned immediately, but resolved later.

Something like this, in your service: -

```
var httpInProgress = false; // used to identify if a request is still in progress

//this is your service method
service.loadData = function(yourParam, defer, shouldNotReturn){
     if(!defer){
         defer = $q.defer();
     }

     if(httpInProgress){
        //if http already in progress, retry again with the same defer object.
        $timeout(function(){service.loadData(yourParam, defer, true);}, 100);
        if(!shouldNotReturn){
             //return a promise but resolve later when we actual deal with http
             return defer.promise;
        }
     }else{
       //do normal stuff if no http in progress
       service.sendActualRequest();
     }
};

service.sendActualRequest = function(yourParam, defer){
     httpInProgress = true;
     $http(request).then(function(res){
        defer.resolve(res);
     }, function(err){
        defer.reject(err);
     }).finally(function(){
         httpInProgress = false;
     });

     return defer.promise;
};
```

Comment: It's hard to use in my service directly but you gave me a new sight. Thanks :)